# Creation of multiple databases from one RDS DB instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am trying to design distributed databases using AWS RDS instances. Now I created a PostgreSQL database instance using AWS RDS service. And I am trying to create multiple databases by using that created instances.

Is it possible to create multiple databases by using one RDS DB instance? If so, how can I do this?

Is there any implementation documentation for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon RDS provides you with a normal PostgreSQL database. You can use standard PostgreSQL commands:

```
CREATE DATABASE name
    [ [ WITH ] [ OWNER [=] user_name ]
           [ TEMPLATE [=] template ]
           [ ENCODING [=] encoding ]
           [ LC_COLLATE [=] lc_collate ]
           [ LC_CTYPE [=] lc_ctype ]
           [ TABLESPACE [=] tablespace_name ]
           [ ALLOW_CONNECTIONS [=] allowconn ]
           [ CONNECTION LIMIT [=] connlimit ]
           [ IS_TEMPLATE [=] istemplate ] ]
```

See: [PostgreSQL `CREATE DATABASE` documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-createdatabase.html)

Comment: Is possible to create multiple databases from same RDS instance?

Comment: The above command creates a database within an RDS instance. You can run it multiple time to create multiple databases. It is standard PostgreSQL, so anything you can do in PostgreSQL you can do in Amazon RDS for PostgreSQL.